# Data Types and Structures in Ada

Tags: ada

I am working on a paper on Ada 83.  We have an assignment that lists the sections of the paper (history, design goals, syntax, etc.,)  The instructor has mentioned that some of us are going to have sections that simply say "This language does not support this feature."

Two of these sections are Data Types and Data Structures.  Well, everything I can see indicated that Ada only has data types and not data structures.  Is this true or am I missing something?  I know this is kinda a weird question (asking about the 1983 version of Ada) but I don't want to make such a big claim without only to find that it was false.

Comment: Can you define "data structures" for the purposes of your paper? For example, back in the day my Data Structures course was taught using Pascal, which is for the most part a feature subset of Ada.

Answer (score 7):

I assume that by "data structures" you mean linked lists, stacks, queues etc.

In Ada83 you could implement data structures, but the standard library didn't contain any. [Non-standard libraries](http://www.adapower.com/original_booch/) were available.

The same was true in Ada95, but the new object-oriented programming features resulted in several open-source container libraries, many of which are still available.

Part of the Ada05 revision was the introduction of a standardised container library `Ada.Containers`, which has been extended in the Ada12 revision.

Answer (score 6):

A lot of things can be called *data structure*. As for Ada, records and arrays would be language-supported data structures. Packages are also a kind of a data structure. Ada 2005's `Ada.Containers` (as mentioned by Simon) are part of the standard library and not of the language itself (your definition may vary; they *are* defined in the LRM).

Complex data structures like stacks, hashed maps, linked lists etc. are usually a feature of the language's standard library, but in some scripting languages, some of these (particularly hashed maps) are actually language features.